# How to use to_date in panda for yyyy-mm-dd format to extract month name?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
df["month"]=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format="%y-%m-%d").dt.month_name() 
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

I used this code to extract month name from the date series in my CSV file. All the dates had a format of yyyy-mm-dd. So i used `%y-%m-%d` to extract month name from the date. But I'm getting key error. Can u tell me where I made the mistake??

Errors:
[image: 0]

[image: 1]

Comment: Getting error even after changing the y to Y.

Comment: So your dataframe doesn't have a column called `date`... what does `print(df.columns)` show you?

Comment: Showing every columns name.

Comment: Well yes... but is there a `date` column? Can you show the output from that?

Comment: yeah!!!! there is no date but when I implement print(df) there's a whole column named date...

Comment: are you sure that `date` isn't the name of the index ?(try `print(df.index.name)`

Comment: It seems you might have had a column called date originally but then you've done things with the DF and that means it's now an index... (just guessing though)

Comment: @JonClements exactly. Date has become index. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use need the capital Y, not y

```
df["month"]=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format="%Y-%m-%d").dt.month_name() 
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
               new
month   
2022-02-01  February
2022-09-10  September
```

Answer (score 2):

Your format string is incorrect you need to use `"%Y-%m-%d"`. `%y` is for two digit years, `%Y` is for four digit years.

you can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Well... Even after changing it I'm getting an error.

Comment: if you update the question with the errors you are receiving we might be able to help more

Comment: Yeah.....Sure!!

Comment: @Sanjay generally unless you've got some really weird datetime format or information in the column that doesn't need to be parsed... you can normally just leave out the `format=` entirely...

Comment: @JonClements still getting the error bro. The same error that i added recently.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, You can use lambda function applied on the **date** column of your dataframe by using the datetime library.

```
from datetime import datetime
df["month"] = df.date.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime('%B'))
```

More information about the formats could be found here. :)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Output below:

[image]